# Set UILabel font size according to its frame size on IOS8?

Tags: ios, ios8, uilabel, uifont

I found a lot of solution with the property “`adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`" , but none of these solutions works on IOS8.

I develop a responsive app and the label font size has to change according to the screen width...

I have :

```
    label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.numberOfLines = 1;
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_DIGITAL size:60];
    [label setMinimumScaleFactor:8.0/label.font.pointSize];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.width, self.height);
    label.text = @"TEXT";
    [self addSubview:valueLabel];
```

Someone has a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059631/autoshrink-on-a-uilabel-with-multiple-lines
use the "adjustFontSizeToFit" category method. That should solve the problem. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your label's auto shrink property as shown in below image.

[image: UILable Autoshrink property]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't use interface builder. Do you know how to do programmatically?

Comment: Are you setting "numberOfLines" property to 1 ?

Comment: Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908334/uilabel-not-autoshrinking-text-to-fit-label-size

Answer (score 0):

Following answer is a hack (not the best solution), but it works, so if you want, you can try:

```
- (void) sizeLabel: (UILabel *) label toRect: (CGRect) labelRect  {

    // Set the frame of the label to the targeted rectangle
    label.frame = labelRect;

    // Try all font sizes from largest to smallest font size
    CGFloat fontSize = 16.0f;
    CGFloat minFontSize = 5.0f;

    // Fit label width wize
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT);

    do {
        // Set current font size
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:label.font.fontName size:fontSize];

        // Find label size for current font size
        CGRect textRect = [[label text] boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
                                                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:label.font}
                                                     context:nil];

        CGSize labelSize = textRect.size;

        // Done, if created label is within target size
        if( labelSize.height <= label.frame.size.height )
            break;

        // Decrease the font size and try again
        fontSize -= 1.0f;

    } while (fontSize > minFontSize);
}
```