# UILabel autoshrink not working

Tags: ios, storyboard, uilabel

I am setting the **Autoshrink** property of `UILabel` but that's not working.

[image]

Following is the **content hugging** and **content compress resistance** values I have set :

[image]

My screen looks like this :

[image]

Text on second label in top green panel is not shrinking.

Comment: You can see my answer on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908334/uilabel-is-not-auto-shrinking-text-to-fit-label-size/50002413#50002413)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the text property from plain to attributed in the inspector and use minimum font scale.
That should work.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. It was happening on a old storyboard so not sure what went wrong. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Yes auto shrink doesn't work for multiple lines in UILabel.you have text with multiple lines, you want to shrink it so that it "fit" with the width. So should it shrink the whole text to fit in one line, or words stay in the same line and shrink to fit each width? The latter is the most common case, but do not forget that the words is also set to arrange themselves in multiple lines. Even if auto-arrangement of the text is disabled, you will have to face with each lines of the text having different font size, as not every words will fit to the width

Comment: I have now set number of lines to 0 but still not shrinking.

Comment: which ios version you used??

Comment: Use minimum Font Scale instead of minimum Font size. It may be help you because minimumFontSize is deprecated in iOS 6.

Comment: @yankitPatel As I know, minumFontSize is still working even at iOS10

Comment: I am trying to use the Autoshrink property but I am not able to see the result. I am using Xcode8. Did anyone get success while using the Xcode8?