# UISegmentedControl labels not fitting

Tags: ios, swift3, uisegmentedcontrol

When using a UISegmentedControl, I have a problem fitting all the labels, precisely in Japanese.
I did not notice the same issue with the other language I used at this point.
Here is my code:

```
    interfaceChoice = UISegmentedControl(items: ["白黒モード", "緑赤青・モード"])

    for i in 0..<interfaceChoice.subviews.count {
        interfaceChoice.subviews[i].tintColor = localColor

        for subSubView in interfaceChoice.subviews[i].subviews {
            if subSubView is UILabel {
                (subSubView as! UILabel).adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            }
        }
    }
```

I would hope the line ..adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth.. would sort things out, but it does not work as one can see in the picture below.
Anyone has an idea as what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: are you restricted to that width?

Comment: What do yo mean by "restricted to that width" ? I want the labels to (automatically) use a font size sot that they can fit in. And I have the whole device width to fit the UISegmentedControl. That's all.

Comment: There are often design restrictions. I would suggest calculating the length of the longest string, and adjusting the width of control accordingly. If the code you had written above had worked as you expected, one label would be smaller than the other, which you probably don't want.

Comment: I do not have any design restrictions. A result similar to the one given in the answer below would graphically be satisfying for me. Calculating the length of the longest string and adjusting the width of the control accordingly seems a bit like giving up to me. The whole purpose of what I was doing was to let the framework take care of this "paper work" for me.

Comment: might read through the various answers and discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908334/uilabel-is-not-auto-shrinking-text-to-fit-label-size You may need to tell it the scale factor as well, though it will still likely shrink the one label's font.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

### Storyboard example

This is how I did it.

1. In a story board, drag and drop a segmented control into the title area of the view controller.

[image]

2. Link the segmented control to an IBOutlet in the view controller.
3. This code

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {

       @IBOutlet weak var interfaceChoice: UISegmentedControl!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           interfaceChoice.removeAllSegments()
           interfaceChoice.insertSegment(withTitle: "白黒モード", at: 0, animated: false)
           interfaceChoice.insertSegment(withTitle: "緑赤青・モード", at: 1, animated: false)
           interfaceChoice.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
           let font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
           interfaceChoice.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], for: .normal)

           interfaceChoice.tintColor = UIColor(red: 27/CGFloat(255), green: 77/CGFloat(255), blue: 102/CGFloat(255), alpha: 1.0)
       }
   }
   ```

*Note: I won't pretend to know exactly why it's not behaving for you, but I hope this can help. If it is absolutely imperative to fix your exact situation, I think we might need more information.*

### Pure code example

This produces the same result as setting it up in the storyboard.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        var interfaceChoice: UISegmentedControl!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            interfaceChoice = UISegmentedControl(items: ["白黒モード", "緑赤青・モード"])
            interfaceChoice.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
            let font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
            interfaceChoice.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], for: .normal)

            interfaceChoice.tintColor = UIColor(red: 27/CGFloat(255), green: 77/CGFloat(255), blue: 102/CGFloat(255), alpha: 1.0)

            self.navigationItem.titleView = interfaceChoice
        }
    }
```

Comment: Let me see if I can get something out of you answer. But I am not using the Storyboard, I am building all in code. And which "more information" would you need?

Comment: How you're adding it to the view hierarchy. Also, are you using a custom font?

Comment: I added it to the view hierarchy as always by using view.addSubview(component).

Comment: In your code you set the fontSize (which is actually what I ended up doing too) but this misses the point of using adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth and let the system worry about size adjustment.

Comment: @michel In my code, I use the navigation item's title view to add it to the view hierarchy, I think this is what you need to do instead. Also, `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` will only [reduce the font size](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620546-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth). So you have to first set the font size to a larger value.

Comment: adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth should indeed  reduce the font size, but it did not that is why I gave up (at least for this time).

Comment: I think you also need to set `minimumFontScale` as well

Comment: @michel You must be setting the font somehow, possibly through UIAppearance proxies, because what you have displayed certainly isn't the default font. I'd be interested to see that code, and the exact code used to add the segmented control to the navigation bar. With those 2 things, I could probably reproduce your exact case.

Comment: Yes indeed as far as I remember I was setting the fonts (as default) and my idea was that the adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth would adjust the size later if ever necessary, but that part didn't work as expected.