# Autoshrink in UILabel only for width?

Tags: ios, swift

I have some ASCII syntax diagrams which must not have line breaks in the middle.

These don't have to be editable so I thought the best way is to use an UILabel with auto shrink option. But this option shrinks the text also if the content doesn't fit the height of the labels frame rectangle.

I just want to shrink only if the content doesn't fit the width. It would be absolutely fine to scroll vertically through the text.

What is the best way to do this with UILabel or any other UI element?

Comment: I cannot understand ... What's your expected result? Do you want to keep a single line only or you want to break into several lines? Also, which option in Autoshrink were you choosing?

Comment: I have a lot of ASCII syntax diagrams. All with variable length and height. Some have 10 lines others have 100. So the UILabel autoshrink function will shrink the whole 100 lines diagram because it doesn't fit height. But this is not what I want. The height should be scrollable. I just want to shrink if the diagram doesn't fit the width to prevent line breaks in the middle of the diagram. I choose auto shrink with minimum font size set. (Hope I explained it clearly now - sorry no native english speaker)

Answer (score 0):

Use UITextView with 'editable' property set to false.

Comment: This doesn't work. UITextView does a line break if the content hits the width border.

Comment: I understand your question. You must divide your diagrams into lines. And   make UILabels per line. And show those using UITableView placing UILabels in UITableViewCell

Comment: But then will shrink the lines with many characters and other lines won't. So those lines won't fit together anymore...

Answer (score 0):

So let me rephrase your question. I guess what you want is a UILabel which can show multiple lines, but the longest line need to fit into the width of UILabel. If this is what you want, well the imagination is weird to me...

But anyway, I feel there's a conflict in your settings. First, allowing multiple lines implies you set "Lines" attribute (number of lines) as 0, which allows unlimited lines. But then Autoshrink will play no effect. I'm afraid it is not possible to be done by just setting the storyboard and instead, you need to write some code.

I guess people have raised related questions earlier, by which they want to dynamically change the font size when the text become too long. I guess you want to take a look about this:

[Autoshrink on a UILabel with multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059631/autoshrink-on-a-uilabel-with-multiple-lines)

The last issue is you also want the scrolling effect (this is why I feel the outlooking will be weird.) But in short, to achieve this you need 1) dynamically change the UILabel height, most likely using the same technique as explained in the reference thread, and 2) wrap the UILabel in a scroll view. Maybe this can achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks... I will try to implement it like this. To the outlooking: As I mentioned my content are syntax diagrams in text. With commands, parameters, arrows and so on. These must not have a line break in the middle. I have no idea to solve it in any other way. The standard autoshrink would shrink the content needlessly and make them harder to read. By scrolling vertically through the diagrams you will be able to understand them without problems. But I would be happy about any other solution.